# Scrapy/Python - Attempting to stagger spiders

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Trying to stagger two spiders:

`spider1` crawls and builds a list of URLs into a .csv

`spider2` crawls from the .csv to then pull specific data

I keep getting this error:
`with open('urls.csv') as file:                                                                                                                                                             FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'urls.csv'`

It looks like `spider1` isn't able to fire first, and/or that python is checking for the file `urls.csv` because of the order of the code and is erroring out because the file doesn't exist yet.

This is the piece to stagger the crawls - it's something I grabbed from gitHub a while back, but the link appears to no longer be up.  I've tried placing this in different spots, and even duplicating or splitting it up.

```
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(spider1)
    yield runner.crawl(spider2)
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

I like to have `urls.csv` to troubleshoot the URLs, but it may be best to store the URLs in a list as a variable [though I haven't figured out the syntax to be able to do that yet]

Below is the full code I'm using.  Any input would be deeply appreciated.  Thank you!

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider1'
    start_urls = [
        'https://tsd-careers.hii.com/en-US/search?keywords=alion&location='
    ]

    custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {r'urls.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'item_export_kwargs': {'include_headers_line': False,}, 'overwrite': True,}}}

    def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.xpath('//@href').getall():
            yield {'url': response.urljoin(job),}

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next-page-caret"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


class spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider2'
    with open('urls.csv') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {r'data_tsdfront.xml': {'format': 'xml', 'overwrite': True}}}

    def parse(self, response):
        reqid = response.xpath('//li[6]/div/div[@class="secondary-text-color"]/text()').getall()
        yield {
            'reqid': reqid,
        }

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(spider1)
    yield runner.crawl(spider2)
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to understand that to use a variable would require a lot of restructuring.

I've done some revising after some more research and experimenting, and this may be ugly but I have everything working as desired. I can improve and restructure as my knowledge and experience grows.

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import pandas as pd

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):   
    name = 'spider1'    
    start_urls = [      
            'https://tsd-careers.hii.com/en-US/search?keywords=alion&location=' 
    ]   

    custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {r'urls.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True,}}}   

    def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.xpath('//@href').getall():
            yield {'url': response.urljoin(job),}       

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next-page-caret"]/@href').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def read_csv(): 
    df = pd.read_csv('urls.csv')
    return df['url'].values.tolist()

class spider2(scrapy.Spider):   
    name = 'spider2'    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in read_csv():
        yield scrapy.Request(url)   

custom_settings = {'FEEDS': {r'data_tsdfront.xml': {'format': 'xml', 'overwrite': True}}}   

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.css('*').getall()
            yield {
            'data': data,   
            }

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():    
    yield runner.crawl(spider1)
    yield runner.crawl(spider2)
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```